# Is it possible to get this PostgreSQL query down from 50ms to the order of a few ms?

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a query that I want to make as fast as possible. It's this:

```
explain analyze
            select
                *
            from
                rtsepezocoav_102999 av
            join rtco_102097 c on
                c.lo_id = av.co_id
            where
                av.ad_id = 335
                and av.pe_id = 70
                and av.se_id = 12
```

I get the following plan:

```
Hash Join  (cost=1238.88..3275.61 rows=40581 width=80) (actual time=10.341..47.707 rows=41238 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (av.co_id = c.lo_id)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719 av  (cost=868.38..2798.54 rows=40581 width=68) (actual time=4.550..17.615 rows=41238 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (ad_id = 335))
        Filter: (pe_id = 70)
        Heap Blocks: exact=360
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719_se_id_ad_id_idx  (cost=0.00..858.23 rows=40581 width=0) (actual time=4.450..4.450 rows=41238 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((se_id = 12) AND (ad_id = 335))
  ->  Hash  (cost=204.67..204.67 rows=13267 width=12) (actual time=5.759..5.759 rows=13267 loops=1)
        Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 699kB
        ->  Seq Scan on rtco_102097 c  (cost=0.00..204.67 rows=13267 width=12) (actual time=0.009..2.125 rows=13267 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.515 ms
Execution Time: 51.100 ms
```

Which is not terrible, I guess. But the actual query is more involved + I'll be running this query in parallel on different shards. So I'm really focussed on getting this lightning quick. Is there anything I'm missing, or is this just the limit of postgres ? It seems a bit 'slow' in my mind, to join 40K records (rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719) with 10K records (rtco).

rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719 has indexes on:
(ad_id, pe_id, se_id)
(ad_id, se_id)
(co_id)

rtco has index on (lo_id)

One of the first things that comes to mind, why does it use a "Bitmap Heap Scan" instead of an index only scan ?

When I do:

```
explain analyze select 1 from rtsepezocoav_102999 av
```

I get an index only scan, and it takes 15ms (also seems long).

I'm on Postgres 12.

Comment: It is returning something like 40k rows.  That is going to take time.

Comment: Execution time is is faster than blink of your eye. How much MS exactly are you expecting and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Can you show us the plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` and run `set track_io_timing=on;` before that (you would need superuser access for that). You can also try to play around with the order of the columns for the index on `rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719` maybe put `pe_id` as the first column. Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: does rtsepezocoav_102999  have an index on co_id ? generally you would want both sides of the join condition indexed

Comment: You cannot easily get an index only scan if you `SELECT *`.

Comment: Seems like a sever case of [Premature Optimization](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/). The total elapses time of 52ms is almost twice as fast as human eye blink rate of 100ms.

Comment: As to your question about why it's not using an index only scan - you are selecting all of the columns.  An index only scan would require all of the columns to be in one index.  Try selecting fewer columns, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx for the tips, but in all honesty I think I was indeed performing a premature opimization...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could add an index on `co_id`. You do have indexes in all the ids on the where, but on the join you only have index on 1 side of the join.

```
rtco has index on (lo_id)

rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719 has indexes on: (ad_id, pe_id, se_id) => this one should have index on co_id
```

With no index on the co_id it ends up doing sequentially scan for the `rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719` table when joining

Comment: Oops, I missed to report some other indexes that I have, including the one you mentioned. I'll update the question.

Comment: In that case, this is just a thought but maybe if you first filter the rtsepezocoav_p_70_103719 table with the  "where
                av.ad_id = 335
                and av.pe_id = 70
                and av.se_id = 12 and then you do the join with less rows in that side could help.
At this moment the query first does the from, then the join and then does the where, so it end up doing the join with some rows that are not relevant to then use the where to filter the relevant results